# Testing complex T-SQL script in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, testing, automated-tests

I am developing a sophisticated data transformation script using T-SQL. The script has to convert the data between the new database scheme and the legacy scheme.

To test the script I perform the following actions:

1. Create or reset both database.
2. Make a small change in the "new" database I want to test (add a new entry, delete one entry etc.)
3. Run the script to sync both instances.
4. Look in the "old" instance whether the change was correctly propagated here.

I do everything manually and this is really a mundane work. What I would like to get is a framework or tool that would automate the steps 1,3 and 4 and would allow me to script my changes and the assertions (like in normal unit test) and run multiple tests.

I looked at the SQL Server Data Tools, but they provide very limited support for SQL unit testing. This is why I am looking for some alternatives or an extended `MSTest` or `xTest` based example of such automation.

Comment: not very clear wht u r doing in ur steps but sounds like u should be able to achieve those steps with SSIS.

Comment: @NitinAgrawal I tried to improve the wording. My steps are just like single unit tests run against two databases, and I want to automate the testing. I am aware of SSIS, but creating SSIS per test would be too expensive in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the complexity of your tests, but, may be, rolling back the changes made during test will help you (as far I understand, the main difficulty is to make an initial state for testing)?

```
-- The table from old database
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)

-- The table from new database
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
```

Sample test (should transfer all non-existing records into old table):

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO
    [Old_Database].[dbo].[People]
SELECT
    New_People.[Id],
    (New_People.[FirstName] + ' ' + New_People.[LastName]) AS FullName
FROM
    [New_Database].[dbo].[People] AS New_People
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Id] FROM [Old_Database].[dbo].[People] WHERE [Old_Database].[dbo].[People].[Id] = New_People.Id)

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    PRINT('Failed!');
ELSE
    PRINT('Passed.');

-- We can look, what was changed
SELECT * FROM [Old_Database].[dbo].[People]

-- Do not commit the changes. This allows to run test many times
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This is similar to how I am going it now. The problem is not to reset the changes (I am using a special field with timestamp of the latest change. But in this case I have to copy the complete script to every test's body and I cannot automate the execution of tests.